# Identifying the fruit or the seed of a tree

Tags: identification

I took this picture of a fruit when visiting an arboretum in zone 6b. I remember the guide talking about an invasive species, but I can't remember if it was related to the fruit or if it was about some other tree.
I have used Google images to find the name of the tree, but it didn't work.
I have the option of waiting until next november to make another visit and to ask the guide, but I hope it won't be the case.
The location of this is [Parcul Dendrologic, Simeria Romania](http://tinyurl.com/hxyzgul).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If those leaves came from the same tree that produced this fruit then my money's on Cornus kousa. The seed case or fruit shown in your photo is well past its best, but still just about recognisable and pretty much umistakeable. This image here shows a particular variety of C. kousa, but fruits are similar on all varieties http://www.mesarbustes.fr/cornus-kousa-cristina-cornouiller-a-fruits-comestibles-greffe.html

Comment: Sure would be nice to have a picture of the entire tree and environment.  How can we better help these people with questions who usually have no idea about plants or even how to ask a proper question?  Honestly, we should have a short questionaire with which to help them form a decent question and know what pictures/info for zones/soil types they need to include.  This going back and forth with tiny amounts of information is crazy.  Or do you think this structure is just fine?

Comment: @stormy I don't have pictures of the surroundings. The place I took this picture is an arboretum, a collection of trees from all over the world. That's why I don't know from what tree or shrub this seed fell from. By the way, a questionaire would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AlinaMitroi - there's enough information in the picture to say it is Cornus kousa - the only other possiblity is Arbutus, which also produces globular red fruits, but is not deciduous. The leaves I see laying on the ground around the fruit appear to be C.kousa, ergo, the tree must be Cornus kousa.

Comment: @AlinaMitroi Thank you for the questionaire vote.  Grins.  Bamboo has definitely answered your question.